# Using jquery to change a div id

Tags: jquery

I have an html page with:

```
<div id="box-"></div>
```

How could I use jquery to change (is append the right word?) `box-` to `box-2353` where 2353, or whatever number, would be set in a separate `.txt` file?

I've found solutions for changing a `class`, but I don't have the option since it's coming from an RSS feed and is already set as an `id`.

Comment: ...I think you forgot to past your code with your question...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (plain Javascript):

```
document.getElementById('box-').id += getTheNumber()
```

Or with jQuery:

```
var $box = $('#box-')
$box.attr('id', $box.attr('id') + getTheNumber())
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GscJR/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.prop`

```
$('#box-').prop('id', $('#box-').prop('id') + '2353');    
$('div[name=div]').html($('div[name=div]').prop('id'));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/29F3L/)**

Comment: You just copied Xeano's fiddle... I see the URL. -1

Comment: @Doorknob Yes, this not is a great code, only i show the use of `.prop` and not `.attr`..

Comment: Yes, but you just copied Xeano's fiddle.

Comment: @Doorknob Ok, changed... xD

Answer (score 0):

Use the [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to manipulate attributes. The id is *"just"* another attribute of the element.

```
var box = $('#box-');
box.attr('id', box.attr('id') + '2353');
```

A short [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jHdKr/1/) of this.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly, now I just need to get it get it to load the 2353 from a text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET", "myfile.txt", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
    if (txtFile.status === 200) {  // Makes sure it's found the file.
      allText = txtFile.responseText; 
      numbers = txtFile.responseText.split("\n"); // Will separate each line into an array
      for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            $('#box-1').replaceWith('<div div="box-'+numbers[i]+'">'+$('#box-1').html()+'</div>');
        }

    }
  }
}
txtFile.send(null);
</script>
```

'#box-1' is the div you want to replace.

Comment: I tried it I couldn't get it to work, I had the 2353 as the only text in the myfile.txt which was in the same folder as the .html, other than that I just copied and pasted this into the top of the .html, div still stays as #box-. I'll try playing with it and see if I can get it to work, thank you.